# What caused my servo to burn out?

Tags: power-supply

I'm working on a servo project. I connected 12 servos to a single Adafruit servo shield and plugged in a 5V 10 amp (http://www.adafruit.com/product/658) switching power supply to the shield. Instantly, the motors became very hot and one of the motor became unresponsive.

What could be the reason for this? The only rational reason would be that a large amount of current went through the motors but physically how could this happen? I thought V = IR, since voltage at 5 V, then current should have been divided evenly across the motors so it would have been very small?

Comment: How were the motors connected? In parallel? In series?

Comment: Looking at the picture on the servo shield (http://www.vetco.net/catalog/images/VUPN5788-1.jpg), the protruding pins in the middle was where the motors were connected, one column is a single motor so I guess all were connected in parallel

Comment: Posting a schematic / drawing / photo of what you wired up plus specifying which motors you used would go a long way towards helping you get answers.

Comment: Also, specifying which power supply you used will help with that part of the question.

Comment: A trivial answer is the servos are wired up incorrectly, a more sophisticated answer is some Arduino pins driving the servos weren't generating PPM pulse, and the servos "didn't like it". So please post your code as well as something showing the way the servos are connected to the shield. (and a part number or link to the switched power supply, in case that contributed something)

Comment: Did the LED indicators light up? I would guess this was due to supply reverse polarity. Did you solder the VCC jumper on the board?

Comment: Measure the output voltage of the supply!  Unless you had special low-voltage servos intended for single-cell applications, or wired things up backwards, that doesn't seem like a failure which should have happened if everything is what it claims to be.

Comment: If servos were not making a grinding sound, the signal was probably fine (it's regulated to 5V I think anyways). I have had servo gear teeth rip off when giving it a wrong pulse, but never overheating and burning out. I would bet on reversed polarity. What servos did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(EDIT: This answered OP's original title question, which was "What happens if you use a load that exceeds the maximum regulated current output from your power supply?")

As for the power supply overload question, it depends on the power supply. Some behaviours include:

- latching the output off
- reducing the output voltage while keeping the output current constant
- hiccupping (switching the output off and on)
- going into thermal shutdown with autorecovery
- blowing a fuse
- blowing up

It will all depend on the power supply itself and the nature of the overload.

Comment: What "power supply overload question"???  Quite clearly, it is not that the supply has been overloaded, but rather that the servos have consumed more power than they are designed to.

Comment: The one that was originally there before OP edited the question. Maybe you don't have the reputation to see the history of the question. The original title was "What happens if you use a load that exceeds the maximum regulated current output from your power supply?"

Comment: Ah, I only focused on there having been no substantial edits to the question body.